# R barplot outside region

Tags: r, rstudio, bar-chart

So I've created a barplot for some data I have with the following code:

```
plot <- barplot(data,
    beside = TRUE,
    col = c("red", "blue", "green"),
    space = c(0, 0.4),
    width = 0.2,
    xlim = c(0, 2),
    ylim = c(0, 1.1),
    legend = c("KNN", "MF1", "MF2"),
    args.legend = list(x = 2.7, y = 1.2),
    yaxt = 'n',
    xpd = TRUE,
    srt = 90
)
text(x = plot,
    y = data + 0.05,
    labels = as.character(round(data, digits = 2)),
    srt = 90,
    xpd = TRUE
)
```

I think the plot looks neat, but... It does not fit the region (I think at least). Are there any ways to keep the width of the bars in picture 1 and still show all 8 groups? My solution so far is to reduce the width of the bars as shown in picture 2.

[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfNnd.png)
[Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMRd4.png)

Comment: Put the command `par(mar=c(4,4,4,4), oma=c(0,0,0,0))` before `barplot` and then modifiy the values of the `mar` parameter according to your needs.

Comment: @MarcoSandri thanks. Not really what I wanted, but thanks anyway. I wish I could kind of scale my barplot, such that the numbers above each bar wouldn't have to be tilted vertically.